# SQL CREATE TABLE syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to make 500 tables all of which are named [1-500] and have only a timestamp and a corresponding value (totalviews)

```
<?php
$i = 1;
while ($i<500) {
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","database");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE \"".$i."\" ( 
    'TheTime' INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY, 
    'TotalViews' INT UNSIGNED
    )";
    if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      };
    echo "1 table created added: ".$i;
    mysqli_close($con);
$i++;
    }
?>
```

But I get error: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"1" ( 'TheTime' INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY, 'TotalViews' INT UNSIGNED )' at line 1.

What Am I doing wrong? Should I be accomplishing this differently?

Comment: Do not use integers as column/table identifiers. Also, creating 500 identical tables sounds like an incredibly bad (and stupid) idea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Table name of: 100 say,  should be in backticks.

I am being pendatic and put all names in backticks but they are not necessary except for reserved words and unusual names.

Here is tested code:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
while ($i<5) {
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","test","test","testmysql");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE `'.$i.'` ('
    .'`TheTime` INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,'
    .'`TotalViews` INT UNSIGNED)';
    if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      };
    echo "1 table created added: ".$i;
    mysqli_close($con);
$i++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: not sure why the answer was down voted? However, thanks for accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have column names enclosed with single quote you can use backticks

so

```
'TheTime'
```

should be

```
`TheTime`
```

and

```
'TotalViews'
```

to

```
`TotalViews`
```

Comment: Thank you but I now still get Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 ( `TheTime` INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY, `TotalViews` INT UNSIGNED )' at line 1

Comment: hmm u have table names as 1,2...etc so u need to enclose them in backtics as well like the col names.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should move your connection before starting while cycle.
Also for DB name use ` instead of ", for fields use ` instead of ' symbol:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

    die();
}

$i = 1;    
while ($i < 500) {
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE `" . $i . "` (
    `TheTime` INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
    `TotalViews` INT UNSIGNED
    )";

    if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    echo "1 table created added: " . $i;
    $i++;
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

PS: I recommend you use object-oriented interface for mysqli, it's more simple. Details: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php